# Ruby on Rails: How do I recursively substitute my params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I really don't want any nulls passed into my server, because it destroys IE when rendered.

I think a before filter in teh ApplicationController would do the trick.

I kinda want to do something like params.gsub(/\000/,"")  but since params is a hash, that won't work.

What is the shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def recursive_gsub(search, replace, value)
  case value
  when String
  value.gsub!(search, replace)
  when Array,Hash
  value.each{|v| recursive_gsub(search, replace, v)}
  end
end
```

Then `recursive_gsub(/\000/,"",params)` *should* work. You could even add this method to `Hash` if you want something prettier like `params.recursive_gsub!(/\000/,"")`.

Comment: part of my example hash is frozen some how... a = {"a" => "b", "c" => "b", "b" => {"d" => "b"}} not sure what's up with that. I thought hashes were always mutable.

Comment: oh.. the keys are frozen... but the values aren't... woot.